# Make OpenSSH use keys located in Dropbox by default?

Tags: ssh, openssh

After moving my public and private keys to my Dropbox for convenience, I'm having trouble getting OpenSSH to look for them there instead of the default `~/.ssh`.

I changed line 54 in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to ...

`AuthorizedKeysFile      ~/Dropbox/.ssh/`

... But even then, connecting to my VPS prompts me for the `user@server's password:` rather than the passphrase for my private key like it's supposed to.

Keep in mind that everything works fine if I specify the location of the private key when connecting with `ssh -i ~/Dropbox/.ssh/id_rsa user@server`, but I would much rather set the default properly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to connect with "ssh -v -v -v -v". Check owner and premission of your ~/Dropbox/.ssh/ folder. Owner must be you, perms must be 700 or similar. You MUST also make sure that your ~/Dropbox folder (and your home folder) is writable by you and only you. If anybody else can write into these folders, then ssh will think that maybe somebody wrote different keys into the dirs and will just ignore the contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `AuthorizedKeysFile` is server option and takes the whole path, not only directory like your example
- Setting client keys is done using option `IdentityFile` in client config, such as:

  ```
  IdentityFile ~/Dropbox/.ssh/id_rsa
  ```

in your `~/.ssh/config`.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize I had to create this file myself since it didn't exist already. Thanks for the help, Jakuje!